# The event on() can be used in a table that is within another table?

Tags: jquery, dom, click

Well this is the code

```
var $p = $("#tabla_inscripcion");
$p.load("Cursos_Existentes.php");
```

Supposedly be charged a table of 2 columns in a name and the other a button. after:

```
$p.on('click','#tabla_cursos button.curso_ex',function(){
var curso = $(this).attr("id");
curso = curso.replace('_ver','');
if($(this).val() == 'no'){
$(this).val("si");
$("#"+curso).after('<tr class="cursos_'+curso+'"></tr>');
$('.cursos_'+curso).load("Horarios_Cursos.php?curso="+curso);
}
else{
$(this).val("no");
$(".cursos_"+curso).remove();
}
});
```

The button will add a row below the row where you clicked, and that row will load a table that will have 3 columns, where one of them will have a button. If you click again the row I was eliminated.

the problem is as follows:

```
$p.on('click','#tabla_cursos #hor_cur tr td button.inscribir',function(){
$.ajax({
type: post,
url: "inscribir_curso.php",
data: "id_curso="+id, 
success: function(){
$("#tabla_inscripcion").load("Cursos_Existentes.php");
}
});
```

Are supposed to click the button to use is made of ajax to send a variable post that without fault will be charged again only without the table row where the button was, but the button does nothing, what is the problem?

I am using a translator, sorry if not understood.

UPDATE 2012/05/11

Well, almost everything is done here in html

```
<div class="tabla_inscripcion" id="tabla_inscripcion" align="center">
</div>

<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
include 'Conexion.php';

session_start();
$id_alumno = $_SESSION['id_login'];

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT curso FROM cursos WHERE id_curso NOT IN (SELECT id_curso FROM inscripsion WHERE id_alumno=$id_alumno)";

$result = mysql_query($sql, $conexion);

echo '<table id="tabla_cursos">';
echo '<tr class="encabezado"><td>CURSOS</td></tr>';

if(mysql_num_rows($result) != 0){
    while($count = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo '<tr id="'.str_replace(' ', '_', $count["curso"]).'">';
        echo '<td>'.$count["curso"].'</td>';
        echo '<td><button value="no" class="curso_ex" id="'.str_replace(' ', '_', $count["curso"]).'_ver">ver</button></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
else{
    echo '<tr><td>no hay cursos disponibles</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

And this is the code that creates the table with three columns

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
include 'Conexion.php';

$curso = str_replace('_', ' ', $_GET["curso"]);
$i=0;

$sql = "SELECT cursos.id_curso, curso, dias, horario, nombre 
    FROM cursos INNER JOIN instructor 
    ON cursos.id_instructor = instructor.id_instructor 
    AND curso='$curso'";

$result = mysql_query($sql, $conexion);


echo '<td>';
echo '<table id="horarios_cur">';
echo '<tr>
    <td id="dia_cur">Días</td>
    <td id="hor_cur">Horario</td>
    <td id="nom_prof">Profesor</td>
    <td id="but_insc"></td>
  </tr>';
if(mysql_num_rows($result) != 0){
   while ($count = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  echo '<tr id="'.$curso.'_'.$i.'">';
  echo '<td id="hor_cur">'.$count["dias"].'</td>';
  echo '<td id="hor_cur">'.$count["horario"].'</td>';
  echo '<td id="nom_prof">'.$count["nombre"].'</td>';
  echo '<td id="but_insc"><button class="inscribir" id="'.$count['id_curso'].'">inscribir</button></td>';
  echo '</tr>';
  $i++;
}
}
else{
  echo '<tr><td id="hor_cur">'.$curso.'</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
echo '</td>';
?>
```

And I may not explain, the problem is not that the code fails, but the button does not react, as the code don't found it

I think it is very long, but I would appreciate reply

Answer (score 0):

```
$p.on('click','#tabla_cursos #hor_cur tr td button.inscribir', function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "inscribir_curso.php",
        data: "id_curso="+id, 
        success: function(){
           $("#tabla_inscripcion").load("Cursos_Existentes.php");
        }
    });
});
```

Not sure if it's just typos in your post on SO or not, but your missing quotes on the "POST", and the ending for the click function. Your selector seems overly long and complicated, but without any HTML it's hard to tell if it's correct or not.